# Blue Snowball Ice usb mic has echo sound

Tags: audio, microphone, echo

I use the `Blue Snowball Ice` usb mic. I have put mic around 6 - 12 inches from my mouth. I have used [screen cast ometic](https://screencast-o-matic.com) Normalize and Reduce Noice functionalities of that tool. But I can hear a big echo or something like that on my audio. i.e. you need to increase the volume of the audio over 60. Can you tell me how to avoid it? I can use Audacity also.

Audio file: https://vocaroo.com/i/s1Fi2oXT8rlu

Comment: Echo is usually due to the person at the other end of a call using speakers not a headset. I have't clicked your random google link to see. If you want people to check video/audio sources, post them to recognised outlets, YouTube, SoundCloud etc

Comment: @Tetsujin Done that. Please see it.